# Angularjs clean URL on localhost

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new on AngularJS and I'm trying to figure out how to get clean URLs on my localhost server (it's a basic LAMP).
The problem is that if I wanna reach localhost/login it works just if I create a link in the index.html (using angular-ui-router). If I try to reach the same URL typing it in the browser's address bar, I get the "404 Not Found" error.

Here the code...

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController">

    <h1>{{message}}</h1>

    <a ui-sref="login" ui-sref-active="active">click me</a>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/MainController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
  angular.module("test", ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl:'login.html'
      });
    });
})();
```

**MainController.js**

```
(function() {
  angular.module("test")
  .controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Homepage";
  });
})();
```

**login.html**

```
<h2>/login page</h2>
```

Any help?

Comment: need to set up htacess on server to use html5Mode

Comment: Thanks man! I suspected it was something server side, but I didn't know angularjs needed it. Thanks to your suggestion, I searched on Google and found the right settings to put in htaccess. I would like to accept it as right answer.